# Qual a origem da expressão "o trabalho dá saúde"?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica

Qual a origem da expressão "O trabalho dá saúde”?

É de Portugal ou de outro país? surgiu na Grécia antes de cristo
reconhecido por inventar remédios com raízes, plantas, entre outros meios os curandeiros estudava criar os remédio conforme fosse as doenças.

Comment: Eu conheço "o trabalho enobrece o homem".

Comment: Eu acho que todas essas preguntas sobre "origem da expressão" acabam sendo de uma qualidade muito baixa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão portuguesa "o trabalho dá saúde" não tem uma história de origem em particular; é um velho dito popular, bastante genérico, do qual existem várias variações na nossa língua ("o trabalho enobrece", "o trabalho dá felicidade") e que, no fundo, dizem a mesma coisa:

> «O trabalho é condição de sustento, de realização pessoal, de integração, de reconhecimento e apoio social. E, portanto, de equilíbrio físico e mental, logo, em princípio, de saúde.» [(Público, 2014)](https://www.publico.pt/2014/07/02/economia/opiniao/o-trabalho-da-saude-1661201)

Ainda assim, podemos ressaltar algumas coisas em relação a estas expressões e a visão que os portugueses (particularmente os mais velhos) têm do trabalho.

Durante o Estado Novo, a propaganda do regime  assentava, sobretudo, na promoção do patriotismo, do cristianismo, da família tradicional e a defesa da ruralidade e do trabalho no campo. E embora nada nesta mensagem seja particularmente novo, esta visão da família pobre e trabalhadora era algo muito presente na propaganda e, portanto, partilhada no ideal dos portugueses da altura:

[image: propaganda]

Em relação à segunda parte da pergunta, é verdade que em vários países existem expressões semelhantes, mas são raros os casos em que se sabe a origem de expressões populares deste género.

Por exemplo, *"Arbeit macht frei"* ("o trabalho liberta") é uma expressão de origem alemã (apesar de ter um equivalente na língua francesa - "le travail durante libre"), uma vez que ficou para a história por ter sido gravada nos portões de vários campos de concentração, embora, originalmente, tenha surgido no título de um romance do alemão Lorenz Diefenbach (1873), no qual diferentes personagens encontram o caminho para a virtude através do trabalho.[Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeit_macht_frei)

Comment: Estudos realizados nos Estados Unidos demonstraram que os idosos que trabalham ou que têm uma atividade regular (trabalho voluntário, por exemplo), adoecem menos e vivem mais.

Comment: Que seja um trabalho saudável. Há uns bem pessimos e desgastantes